# searching within a Node on a CSB+ tree

Tags: data-structures, b-tree, search-tree

I'm reading the paper, [making B+-trees cache conscious in main memory](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=335449). In **Section 3.1.2**, authors describe several approaches to searching within a CSB+ tree node.

Tha *basic* approach is to simply do a binary search using a conventional while loop.

The *uniform* approach is through **code expansion**, unfolding the while loop into `if-then-else` statements assuming all the keys are used.

Authors give the following example which exhibits an unfolding of the search for a node with up to 9 keys. The number in a node represents the position of the key being used in an `if` test

```
              4
            /   \
           2     6
          / \   / \
         1   3 5   8
                  / \
                 7   9
```

Then comes the confusing part:

> If only 5 keys were actually present, we could traverse this tree with exactly **3** comparisons. On the other hand, an unfolding that put the deepest subtree at the left instead of the right would need **4** comparisons on some branches.

So why would it need more comparisons in the following tree:

```
              6
            /   \
           4     8
          / \   / \
         2   5 7   9
        / \
       1   3
```

Furthermore,

> if we knew we had only five valid keys, we could hardcode a tree that, on average, used **2.67** comparisons rather than 3.

How does **2.67** come about?

Any hints would be appreciated. Also, a link directing me to **code expansion** knowledge would be helpful.

Actually, I'm not sure whether it's appropriate to ask a question on a paper because some key information may have been left out when transcribed here (the question may need reformatting). I just wish there could be someone who happens to have read the paper.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is the following quotation from the same section:

> we pad all the
>   unused keys (keyList[nKeys..2d-1]) in a node
>   with the largest possible key

Also is is important that in B+/CSB+ tree we search not for node values, but for intervals between these values. A set of possible values is split by 5 keys into 6 intervals.

Since most of the right sub-tree is filled with the largest possible key (L), we need less comparisons than usual:

```
              4
            /   \
           2     L
          / \   / \
         1   3 5   L
                  / \
                 L   L
```

Right descendant of root node has largest possible key, there is no need to check any node to the right of it. And exactly 3 comparisons are needed for every interval:

```
interval   comparisons
up to 1    k>4, k>2, k>1
 1..2      k>4, k>2, k>1
 2..3      k>4, k>2, k>3
 3..4      k>4, k>2, k>3
 4..5      k>4, k>L, k>5
 5..L      k>4, k>L, k>5
```

If we put the deepest subtree at the left, we have a tree, where non-empty nodes are placed one level deeper:

```
              L
            /   \
           4     L
          / \   / \
         2   5 L   L
        / \
       1   3
```

Search for node "1" in this tree requires to compare the key with 4 different nodes: L, 4, 2, and 1.

If we know we have only five valid keys, we have the following tree:

```
              2
            /   \
           1     4
                / \
               3   5
```

Here we can arrange comparisons in a way, that gives 2.67 comparisons on average:

```
interval   comparisons
up to 1    k>2, k>1
1..2       k>2, k>1
2..3       k>2, k>4, k>3
3..4       k>2, k>4, k>3
4..5       k>2, k>4, k>5
5..L       k>2, k>4, k>5
```

"Code expansion" is not a widely used term, so I cannot give you the most relevant link. I think, this is not very different from ["Loop unwinding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding).

Comment: I don't know whether it's a naive question but the average given by your example is 2.8 rather than 2.67.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it correctly explains, why we need 2.67 comparisons.